# Why openssl ignore -days for expiration date for self signed certificate?

Tags: openssl, self-signed-certificate

I have a bash script that generates a `self-signed` certificate and works perfectly fine:

```
#! /bin/bash

# Generate self signed root CA cert
openssl req -nodes -x509 -days 358000 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/C=IR/ST=TEH/L=Torento/O=CTO/OU=root/CN=es.example.com/emailAddress=info@example.com"

# Generate server cert to be signed
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 358000 -keyout server.key -out server.csr -subj "/C=IR/ST=TEH/L=Torento/O=CTO/OU=server/CN=es.example.com/emailAddress=info@example.com"

# Sign the server cert
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt

# Create server PEM file
cat server.key server.crt > server.pem


# Generate client cert to be signed
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 358000 -keyout client.key -out client.csr -subj "/C=IR/ST=TEH/L=Torento/O=CTO/OU=client/CN=es.example.com/emailAddress=info@example.com"

# Sign the client cert
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAserial ca.srl -out client.crt

# Create client PEM file
cat client.key client.crt > client.pem
```

When I check the expiration time of the generated `client.pem`, it shows expiration time at 10th of Aug.:

```
$ openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in client.pem
notAfter=Aug 10 12:32:07 2018 GMT
```

What is the problem with expiration date?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The validity is set with `openssl x509` and not with `openssl req`.
It you put the `-days` option with `x509` command, it will work.

You get the 30/08 because there isn't a `-days` option that override the default certificate validity of 30 days, as mentioned in `x509` the man page:

> -days arg
>   specifies the number of days to make a certificate valid for. The default is 30 days.

Side note, generating certificate with 358000 days (980 years!) validity is too long if you want reasonable security.

Comment: +1 Oh I see! I didn't know `-days` belongs to x509. It is now set to the desired date. Thanks.

Comment: I made the `-days` option work from an `openssl req` command when I did it from the command line, but it would not work when I specified the number of days as a variable in a shell script.

Comment: @oliv, what is the security problem with not making your certificates expire in a timely manner? If you have an OCSP server, that should be fine, right?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 Any certificate should have a reasonable expiry time. My point is within 980 years, it is likely that the certificate cipher algorithm will be broken or at least you can change it with a better algorithm...

Answer (score 29):

The validity period of a certificate is set when that certificate is generated.

- **`openssl req`** by itself generates a *certificate signing request* (CSR). **`-days`** specified here will be ignored.
- **`openssl x509`** issues a certificate from a CSR. This is where **`-days`** should be specified.

But:

- **`openssl req -x509`** combines **`req`** and **`x509`** into one; it generates a CSR and signs it, issuing a certificate in one go. That's why **`req`** supports the **`-days`** flag, as it passes it internally to the `x509` command.

Comment: Note that when using `openssl req -x509` you still can't put the days parameter in the config file, only the command line parameter works.